# How can I to do this?, but with lines join

Tags: tables, booktabs, rowcolor

[image]

I used Excel2Latex

```
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
\cmidrule{1-1}    \rowcolor[rgb]{1,1,0}    & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{\cellcolor[rgb]{1,1,1}} \\
\cmidrule{1-2}       &    & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} \\
\cmidrule{1-3}       &    &    & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} \\
\cmidrule{1-4}       &    &    &    & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} \\
    \midrule
    \rowcolor[rgb]{.514,.235,.047}    & \cellcolor[rgb]{1,1,1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{1,1,1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{1,1,1} & \cellcolor[rgb]{1,1,1} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
```

Comment: You mean the vertical lines and the horizontal do not intersect? Do not use the rules from booktabs: they have some vertical padding, or  set the padding to $0$ (it is set with the lengths `\aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep`).

Comment: The thicker delimiters as you go down and right on the table? or the triangular table itself delimited?

Comment: @JaredLo the thicker delimiters?? all have the same thickness, that effect is the cause of rendering.xD

Comment: ok @Bernard Thanks for the tip, I will find out more about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks very much like a Young tableau:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ytableau}

\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{1,1,0}
\definecolor{mybrown}{rgb}{.514,.235,.047}

\begin{document}

\begin{ytableau}
  *(myyellow) \\
  & \\
  && \\
  &&& \\
  *(mybrown) &&&&
\end{ytableau}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @egreg , this is very simple, easy,, and fast..xD

Answer (score 5):

With the help of `hhline` instead of `booktabs`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}

\newcommand{\nocell}{\multicolumn{1}{r}{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{|r|r|r|r|r|}
      \hhline{|-|~~~~}    
        \cellcolor[rgb]{1,1,0}          & \nocell & \nocell & \nocell & \nocell \\
      \hhline{|-|-|~~~}   
                                        &         & \nocell & \nocell & \nocell \\
      \hhline{|-|-|-|~}          
                                        &         &         & \nocell & \nocell \\
      \hhline{|-|-|-|-|}         
                                        &         &         &         & \nocell \\
      \hline
        \cellcolor[rgb]{.514,.235,.047} &         &         &         &         \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: wonderfull, thanks,@leandriis

Comment: Are you sure the `\nocell` commands are necessary?

Answer (score 4):

A small variation of  [@leandriis's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518336/how-can-i-to-do-this-but-with-lines-join/518345#518345):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline}% part of shipunov bundle
\usepackage{cellspace}
    \setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
    \setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage{xparse}
    \NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mcc{O{1}m}
        {\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
  \begin{tabular}{|*{5}{Sr|}}
    \hhline{-~~~~}
    \cellcolor[rgb]{1,1,0}{}    & \mcc[4]{}     \\
    \hhline{--~~~}
        &   & \mcc[3]{}                         \\
    \hhline{---~~}
        &   &   & \mcc[2]{}                     \\
    \hhline{----~}
        &   &   &   & \mcc{}                    \\
    \hhline{*5{-}}
    \cellcolor[rgb]{.514,.235,.047} 
        &   &   &   &                           \\
    \hhline{*5{-}}
   \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @Zarko....mmm..analyzing your code..xD

Comment: I just understood your command \ mcc,is great.